# Get ListID of a Subscriber's Publication List programatically?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

Is it possible to get subscriber's ListID of a Publication List?
A retrieve from _Unsubscribes gives me only AllSubscribers listID. 
I've tried every API from MC, I can't get that ListID.

```
set @rows = LookupRows('_ListSubscribers','SubscriberKey', @email)
set @count = RowCount(@rows)
set @field = @bb_count
IF @count > 0 THEN
   set @field = Field(Row(@rows, 1), "ListID")
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, easiest is probably with the following method.

1. Navigate to Email Studio and open up the Publication List.
2. Now hover around the Publication List name in upper-left area and look at below.

Here's a screencap where to look:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I had to be more explicit, I need a way to get that listID programatically.