# How can Salesforce users manage Publication list preferences inside using MC Connector?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, publicationlist

How can one maintain a list of publication lists inside MC and allow service agents to manage an individual subscribers publication list preference within SC?

I imagine we could do this using automation studio querying data extensions and then doing a file import but is there an out-of-the-box solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution as Publication Lists vary by organization and could not be related to any standard Sales Cloud fields.

There are a couple of options that can be done to manage them:

**1)** Salesforce apex by building a custom solution that would do the update to SFMC Publication List.

**2)** Using (as you mentioned) continuously running Automation Studio to query SF field values and importing these values to Publication Lists.

For client side management it's typical to build a custom Preference Center that has the Publication Lists on them, with these populating in real-time by Salesforce fields by using `RetrieveSalesforceObjects` function and the same way they are updated by `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` whenever users make any changes.

With an additional SSJS script piece that would be using Salesforce field values to update corresponding Publication Lists through their [**ListID**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235522/get-listid-of-a-subscribers-publication-list-programatically) values.